# Ambiguous constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to create a simple date class, but I get an error on my main file that says, "call of overloaded Date() is ambiguous."  I'm not sure why since I thought as long as I had different parameters for my constructor, I was ok.  Here is my code:

header file:

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
using std::string;

class Date
{
public:
    static const int monthsPerYear = 12; // num of months in a yr
    Date(int = 1, int = 1, int = 1900); // default constructor
    Date(); // uses system time to create object
    void print() const; // print date in month/day/year format
    ~Date(); // provided to confirm destruction order
    string getMonth(int month) const; // gets month in text format
private:
    int month; // 1 - 12
    int day; // 1 - 31 
    int year; // any year

    int checkDay(int) const;
};

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

Date::Date()
{
    time_t seconds = time(NULL);
    struct tm* t = localtime(&seconds);
    month = t->tm_mon;
    day = t->tm_mday;
    year = t->tm_year;
}

Date::Date(int mn, int dy, int yr)
{
    if (mn > 0 && mn <= monthsPerYear)
        month = mn;
    else
    {
        month = 1; // invalid month set to 1
        cout << "Invalid month (" << mn << ") set to 1.\n";
    }

    year = yr; // could validate yr
    day  = checkDay(dy); // validate the day

    // output Date object to show when its constructor is called
    cout << "Date object constructor for date ";
    print();
    cout << endl;
}

void Date::print() const
{
    string str;
    cout << month << '/' << day << '/' << year << '\n';

    // new code for HW2
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(3) << day;  // prints in ddd
    cout << " " << year << '\n';             // yyyy format

    str = getMonth(month);

    // prints in month (full word), day, year
    cout << str << " " << day << ", " << year << '\n';
}
```

and my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    Date date1(4, 30, 1980);
    date1.print();
    cout << '\n';

    Date date2;
    date2.print();


}
```

Comment: I agree with what GMan wrote. But, also if you declare default constructor private, compiler complains about the same error. Actually, it tries to assemble two "same" or identical methods.

Comment: You should also include your parameter names in your header.  While they aren't technically necessary, there is no way to know if the user is supposed to provide (month, day, year) or (day, month, year) without digging into the source file.  I would also second GMan's advice about not providing the default parameters at all.  Under what circumstances would somebody want some random day, so long as its in June?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Date(int = 1, int = 1, int = 1900); // default constructor
Date(); // uses system time to create object
```

These are both callable with no parameters. It can't be default constructed, because it's ambiguous how to construct the object.

Honestly, having those three with default parameters doesn't make much sense. When would I specify one but not the others?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the two constructors:

```
Date(int day, int month, int year)
{
  this->day = day;
  this->month = month;
  this->year = year;
}
Date(); // uses system time to create object
{
  this->day = 1;
  this->month = 1;
  this->year = 1900;
}
```